# Swiper js don't swipe. Pagination not showing hte right page number

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to the swiper.

[I want to make slide like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdLHR.png)

[But becomes like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs1jg.png)

I want to move the first element to center and make disappeare the left element.
I tried "padding" "margin" to move and change size of element but didn't work well.

How can I centered the element and make disappeare the left element?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
  var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 62.5,
  centeredSlides: true,
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 80,
      centeredSlides: false,
    },
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
    formatFractionCurrent: function (n) {
      return '0' + n;
    },
    formatFractionTotal: function (n) {
      return '0' + n;
    },
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

});
```

```css
.swiper {
  padding-top:calc(10/ 1366 * 100vw);
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;

}

.swiper-wrapper {
  padding-bottom: calc(136/ 1366 * 100vw);
}

.swiper-slide {
  border:1px solid pink;
  max-width:100%;
  width: calc( 552.14/ 1366 * 100vw);
  height: calc( 231/ 1366 * 100vw);
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:calc( 30/ 1366 * 100vw);
  border: 6px solid #B5E9EE;
  margin: calc( -14/ 1366 * 100vw);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-shadow: calc(8/ 1366 * 100vw) calc(8/ 1366 * 100vw) calc(9/ 1366 * 100vw) rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
}

.slide_text {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: calc(51/ 1366 * 100vw);
    padding-right: calc(6/ 1366 * 100vw);
    gap: calc(40/ 1366 * 100vw);
  
}

.num {
  font-family: NotoSansJP-Black;
  font-size: calc(36/ 1366 * 100vw);
  line-height: calc(43.2/ 1366 * 100vw);
  color: #1F2774;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #1F2774;
}

.text {
  font-family: NotoSansJP-Regular;
  font-size: calc(36/ 1366 * 100vw);
  line-height: calc(43.2/ 1366 * 100vw);
}

.swiper-pagination{
  position: absolute;
    font-family: NotoSansJP-Bold;
    font-size: calc( 28/ 1366 * 100vw);
    line-height: calc( 40/ 1366 * 100vw);
    top: calc( 37/ 1366 * 100vw);
    left: calc( 81/ 1366 * 100vw);
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: calc( 115/ 1366 * 100vw);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  width: calc( 60/ 1366 * 100vw);
  height: calc( 61/ 1366 * 100vw);
  background-color: #F6F3DC;
  border-radius: calc( 100/ 1366 * 100vw);
  color: transparent;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  width: calc( 60/ 1366 * 100vw);
  height: calc( 61/ 1366 * 100vw);
  background-color: #F6F3DC;
  border-radius: calc( 100/ 1366 * 100vw);
  color: transparent;
}

.gallery_navigation .fa-chevron-left:before {
    content: "\f053";
    font-size: calc( 28/ 1366 * 100vw);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( 17/ 1366 * 100vw);
    left: calc( 23/ 1366 * 100vw);
    color: black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.gallery_navigation .fa-chevron-right:before {
    content: "\f054";
    font-size: calc( 28/ 1366 * 100vw);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( 17/ 1366 * 100vw);
    left: calc( 24/ 1366 * 100vw);
    color: black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.gallery_navigation {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: calc( 52/ 1366 * 100vw) 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc( 276/ 1366 * 100vw);
    left: calc( 540/ 1366 * 100vw);
    text-align: center;
    top: calc( 238/ 1366 * 100vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="slide_text">
            <div class="num">01</div>
            <div class="text">カードお申し込み</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="slide_text">
            <div class="num">02</div>
            <div class="text">入会審査・カード発行</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="slide_text">
            <div class="num">03</div>
            <div class="text">カード到着行</div>
          </div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide_text">
            <div class="num">04</div>
            <div class="text">アプリをダウンロード</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="slide_text">
            <div class="num">05</div>
            <div class="text">アプリでカード番号を確認</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery_navigation">
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="far fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="far fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must call swiper as (change your JS )

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',
```

you changed the swiper HTML struct, that's why your JS code is not working.

I recommend https://codesandbox.io/s/6mu6ve?file=/index.html:2163-2206 first just add default swiper and run. Then edit your HTML. that's the simple way.

Comment: Thanks for help. I followed your way but still can't get to solve the problem. I edited question. Appreciate if you give me another help when you have. Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/NWMMMXQ?editors=1111 just check it out i fixed the JS command. Your code is not working cause, 

" new Swiper('.swiper .mySwiper'"  its meaning  "swiper class" under element of "mySwiper" class. its wrong.  its must be  " new Swiper('.swiper.mySwiper'"  or " new Swiper('.mySwiper'"    you can check it CSS or Jquery Selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: i stuck with " new Swiper('.mySwiper'" . But problem is that i can't change the width of element properly. i set " max-width: calc( 552.14/ 1366 * 100vw);
  width:  100%;" to ".mySwiper" but couldn't change the width properly. it becomes much smaller than i want to. i tried set width to ".swiper-slide" , but didn't work.

Comment: css codes looking so complicated. you can use only "max-width:100% " I think you don't need calc(40/ 1366 * 100vw);  i just changed some CSS codes and remove all .swiper-slide CSS properties. and looking good. just give normal-simple properties.   you can see on: https://codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/NWMMMXQ?editors=1111

Comment: i think i get  closer to the answer. thank you. now i need to move first element to center. i thought  "centeredSlides: true," can move element to center. i tried "padding" "margin" to move and change the size of element but didn't work well. how can i move element to center?

Comment: @kenken https://codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/NWMMMXQ?editors=1111 can you check again?